# Edittext freezes when calling Editable.clearSpans() inside the onTextChanged Listener

Tags: android, kotlin

The code below crashes if I start typing in the edit text.
However if I set some String like `"Hello asdf"` to the edit text before the listener, the code will run as expected; the `"asdf"` String will be bold until I clear the 'f' from end of the string then the edit text UI will freeze, no crashes though.
It seems like the problem is the `it?.clearSpans()` method.

Any thoughts?

```
editText.addTextChangedListener {
    val TEXT = "asdf"
    if (it?.contains(TEXT) == true) {
        val i = it.toString().indexOf(TEXT)
        it.setSpan(
            StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
            i,
            i + TEXT.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    } else {
        it?.clearSpans()
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? Do you have a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the span, the `textChangedListener` is triggered again, so it gets itself into an infinite loop.

You need an exit condition to stop this. Maybe check if the text is already empty:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener {
        if(!it.toString().isBlank()) {
                    val TEXT = "asdf"
                    if (it?.contains(TEXT) == true) {
                        val i = it.toString().indexOf(TEXT)
                        it.setSpan(
                                StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                                i,
                                i + TEXT.length,
                                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                        )
                    } else {
                        it?.clearSpans()
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is an infinite loop. Even if I call editText.text.clearSpans() outside of the textChangedListener without setting any listener, the EditText ui will still freeze. The clearSpans method is still the problem.